# Incorrect achievement icon in Achievements dropdown

Tags: bug, design

The dropdown uses Music.SE design of badge even when displaying a badge from a different site.

Here I have a badge on Mechanics.SE but there is a little note sitting there in the Achievements box - and I have checked this happens with ones from other sites too.

[image]